# Relação Tem-um em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, nullpointerexception, encapsulamento

Eu tentei fazer uma relação tem-um em C# e não estou conseguindo e nem sei se é recomendado fazer.

Segue meu código que da erro:

> System.NullReferenceException Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.endereco.rua = "guaranesia";

        Console.WriteLine(cliente.endereco.rua);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Cliente
{
    public string name{get; set;}
    public string idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco endereco;
}

class Endereco
{
    public string rua { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        cliente.endereco.rua = "guaranesia";
        WriteLine(cliente.endereco.rua);
    }
}

class Cliente {
    public string name{get; set;}
    public string idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco endereco = new Endereco();
}

class Endereco {
    public string rua { get; set; }
    public string bairro { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TABaPr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p67ufE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Basic.cs).

Faça a classe trabalhar por você. Encapsule a implementação. Torne o consumidor mais limpo e não obrigue ele ter ciência de como ele deve usar as partes da classe. Você usou a *tag* [encapsulamento](/questions/tagged/encapsulamento) que mostra que você entende que deva usar esta forma, agora precisa implementar assim. Você também deveria considerar tornar o próprio campo `endereco` como uma propriedade.

Na verdade em uma classe real muito provavelmente você deveria ter [construtores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Algo assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
         var cliente = new Cliente("João", "20", "Rua Torta", "Centro");
         WriteLine(cliente.Endereco.Rua);

    }
}

class Cliente {
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string Idade {get; set;}
    public Endereco Endereco {get; set;}

    public Cliente(string nome, string idade, string rua, string bairro) {
        Nome = nome;
        Idade = idade;
        Endereco = new Endereco(rua, bairro);
    }
}

class Endereco {
    public string Rua {get; set;}
    public string Bairro {get; set;}
    //Note que não é preciso criar um construtor Endereco() já que ele não fará nada extra
    //O compilador criará um para você
    public Endereco(string rua, string bairro) {
        Rua = rua;
        Bairro = bairro;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NmmtMG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RJRJ07). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/BasicBetter.cs).

Comment: Acredito que este tipo de codigo numa classe real poderia prejudicar a legibilidade do codigo.
Afinal inicializar objetos com construtores muito longos podem tornar o codigo mesmo legivel.
Desta forma, prefiro utilizar Inicializadores do Objeto à Construtores.

Comment: Também prefiro mas usei mais para mostrar como pode-se fazer, mas vou editar para colocar o exemplo que você falou.

Answer (score 2):

Tens que inicializar a propriedade `endereco` antes de a poderes usar.

O melhor sitio para o fazer e' no constructor.

```
class Cliente
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Idade { get; set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public Cliente()
    {
        Endereco = new Endereco();
    }
}
```

Duas notas:

- Em C#, a convencao e' usar [PascalCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k(v=vs.71).aspx) para nomes de propriedades
- ***Quase* nunca** se devem expor *fields* publicos! No codigo acima, substitui o field por uma propriedade (nota o `{get; set;}`).

Para ler: [Jon Skeet - Why Properties Matter](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

você tem que instancia endereço primeiro:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.endereco = new Endereco();
    cliente.endereco.rua = "guaranesia";

    Console.WriteLine(cliente.endereco.rua);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```